# Dynamic widths inside two left floated columns

Tags: html, css

Imagine the site:

```
[list][     iframe     ]
```

both columns must be set next to each other, and has variable widths. I saw many solution, for example this: http://www.sitepoint.com/forums/showthread.php?615554-Floating-100-of-Remaining-Width but thats not the case. I dont have fixed widths, nor dynamics - the left column must be as thin as its content, and the iframe must fill all the remaining space.
jQuery is enabled to use for this case. In addition, how to detect, if the width of list changed?

http://jsfiddle.net/trgC3/

Comment: can you provide us with some code in JSFiddle?

Comment: Found an example that someone else wrote :

http://jsfiddle.net/qx32C/36/

Comment: Oliver, you saved my day, post it so that I can "accept" it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<table style="width:100%;">
    <tr>
        <td style="border:1px solid black;width:100px;height:10px;"></td>
        <td style="border:1px solid black;height:10px;"></td>
    </tr>
</table>
<br /><br />

<div class="lineContainer">
    <div class="left"></div>
    <div class="right"></div>
</div>

.lineContainer {
    overflow: hidden; /* clear the float */
    border: 1px solid #000
}
.lineContainer div {
    height: 10px
} 
.left {
    width: 100px;
    float: left;
    border-right: 1px solid #000
}
```

Comment: a little addition: how to stretch everything to 100 and adding scrollbars?

Answer (score 1):

try using `display: table-cell`
http://jsfiddle.net/YRTM9/

```
<div class='table-div'>
    <div class='left'>
        hello!
    </div>
    <div class='right'>
        <iframe src='http://www.stackoverflow.com'>
        </iframe>
    </div>
</div>
```

with following CSS

```
.table-div {
    display: table;
    width: 100%;
}

.left {
    display: table-cell;
    vertical-align: top;
}

.right {
    display: table-cell;
    width: 100%;
}

.right iframe {
    width: 100%;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I'm on board with those who think about table, but I'd rather add `width: 100%` only for column with iframe. Here is the spec

> For each column, determine a maximum and minimum column width from the
>   cells that span only that column. The minimum is that required by the
>   cell with the largest minimum cell width (or the column 'width',
>   whichever is larger). The maximum is that required by the cell with
>   the largest maximum cell width (or the column 'width', whichever is
>   larger).

[see demo](http://jsfiddle.net/Vicky_007/BnDEQ/24/)

but if you need iframe to keep ratio, you'll have to wrap it div and use some hack